# Buttons work using jQuery append() but not using kendo template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, kendo-ui

i'm working on some stuff with kendo and i'm having an issue i can't figure out how solve it ..

first here is my code :

html:

```
<div data-role="view" id="drawer-prendreRendezVous" data-layout="drawer-layout" data-title="Mondial Relay" data-before-show="SuiviColisViewHelper.I().PrendreRendezVousManageBeforeShow">
    <div id="headerPriseRendezVous" style="width:100%;height:40px;margin-top:6px;">
        <div id="headerPriseRendezVousImg" style="padding-top:4px;padding-left:8px;position:relative; float:left; ">
            <img src="./img/clock.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="headerPriseRendezVousImg" style="position: relative; float:left;margin-left:20px; margin-top:10px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;color:rgb(120,120,120);"> <span>Votre Rendez Vous</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentPriseRendezVous" data-template=""></div>
</div>
```

the template :

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="contentPriseRendezVousTemplate">
    <div style="width:100%;height:2px;background-color:rgb(120,120,120); margin-top:5px;"></div>
    # for (var index = 0; index < Creneaux.length; ++index) {#
              <a href="drawer-finalisationPriseRendezVous" data-click="suiviColisControler.FinaliserRendezVous" data-date="#: Creneaux[index].Date #" data-heure-debut="#: Creneaux[index].HeureDebut #" data-heure-fin="#: Creneaux[index].HeureFin #" data-role="button">Test</a>
    #}#
</script>
```

the code i'm using to set the template:

```
var template = kendo.template($("#contentPriseRendezVousTemplate").html());
var result = template(obj);
$("#contentPriseRendezVous").html(result);
```

if i do that, it work the first time, i get my buttons ...
but if i go back and come back after that, it doesn't work anymore ..

if i use jQuery instead of the code above like this :

```
for (var i = obj.Creneaux.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   $("#contentPriseRendezVous").append('<a href="drawer-finalisationPriseRendezVous" data-click="suiviColisControler.FinaliserRendezVous" data-date="' + obj.Creneaux[i].Date + '" data-heure-debut="' + obj.Creneaux[i].HeureDebut + '" data-heure-fin="' + obj.Creneaux[i].HeureFin + ' " data-role="button"></a>');
};
```

it work perfectly well, that is the part i don't understand ... do i have a problem with my template ... am i doing something bad ...

thank you for helping ;)

Comment: what do you exactly mean with 'if i go back and come back after that'? are you reloading the page?

Comment: Let's say I go from page 1 to 2 where 2 is the page with the template, the first time that's okay, I get back to the first page and go to the second one one more time, it doesn't work with template but does work using jquery

Comment: Are you using the mobile version of Kendo? @bottus